# Python package I created not importing correctly in Docker container

Tags: python, docker, flask

I created a package out of a project and I want to run that package in a Docker container. The package is a Flask application and after installing the package locally I can run the project with `FLASK_APP=packagename` and `flask run`.  When I do the same in the Docker container I get the error `Error: Could not import "packagename.packagename".`
This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7
FROM pytorch/pytorch

MAINTAINER Nikolay Valkov nikolay1499@gmail.com

# set a directory for the app
WORKDIR /usr/app/

# copy all the files to the container
COPY . .

# install dependencies
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

WORKDIR /usr/app/src/

RUN pip install -e .

WORKDIR /usr/app/src/packagename

# tell the port number the container should expose
EXPOSE 5000

ENV FLASK_APP packagename

# run the command
CMD flask run
```

Any ideas why this occurs only in the Docker container and not locally.

Comment: you might try to COPY your package to workdir folder

Comment: yout can say "ADD /usr/src/packagename packagename" it should add it to your working directory

Comment: Does it work if you don't switch the `WORKDIR` into the subdirectory?  By Python's normal resolution rules, I'd expect it to try to load `./packagename/packagename.py`, which would require you to start in the parent directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can try do it like this, it should copy the package to your working directory:
changes replace WORKDIR with ADD OR COPY CMD

```
FROM python:3.7
FROM pytorch/pytorch

MAINTAINER Nikolay Valkov nikolay1499@gmail.com

# set a directory for the app
WORKDIR /usr/app/

# copy all the files to the container
COPY . .

# install dependencies
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

WORKDIR /usr/app/src/

RUN pip install -e .

ADD /usr/app/src/packagename packagename

# tell the port number the container should expose
EXPOSE 5000

ENV FLASK_APP packagename

# run the command
CMD flask run
```

Comment: Sadly this did not help. It says that it cannot find the packagename now.

Comment: is this the correct path to your package on your host machine /usr/app/src/packagename  ??  if not try to change it to the correct path . it should add the package in your working directory(inside container)